# How to use a custom font in CSS?

Tags: css

I found the most beautiful font [here](http://fontsforweb.com/font/show/?id=78041). I want to use it. I tried following:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(http://fontsforweb.com/font/show/?id=78041);
}

div {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
}
```

(Source: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp)

Comment: Did you read the How to section of that page?

Comment: The page you link to provides an embedded link that you can use, and instructions for doing so.  You just have to register.  See "How to embed this webfonts [sic] on your website" on this page:  http://fontsforweb.com/font/show/?id=78041

Answer (score 0):

That is not source for font its just website where you can download it. Download font and place in folder fonts then change your code src to that path.

Answer (score 0):

Download the full zip file, Extract it then put it in your project then use this code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(MonsieurPomme.woff);
}

div {
font-family: myFirstFont;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the font files and add links to the various formats, depending on which browsers you want to support:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/ for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Using font-face.

```
@font-face{
     font-family: ((fontName));
     src: url(fontname.woff);
}
```

Then you can call it just as how you call other fonts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to directly link to the font file instead of just the webpage.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFont;
    src: url('font.eot'); /* IE9 Compatible Modes */
    src: url('font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('font.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
         url('font.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
         url('font.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('font.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */

}
div {
    font-family: 'myFont', serif;
}
```